# Does the Dispose method on System.ComponentModel.Component release event callbacks?

Tags: c#

I am using a simple [Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) in my code, and I have a callback that gets invoked once the time is up.

```
public TimerViewModel(int interval) {
    m_timer = new Timer(interval);
    m_timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
    // Other stuff.
}
```

Then I have a dispose method which disposes my class

```
public void Dispose() {
    m_timer.Dispose();
    // Dispose some more stuff.
}
```

Now I would like to know if I am supposed to unregister my callback with `m_timer.Elapsed -= timer_Elapsed` before I dispose the timer or is that done anyway be the timers dispose method?

I have read the MSDN site about the [Timers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) and the one about [Component](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component(v=vs.110).aspx), but both only state that the Dispose method "Releases all resources used by the Component", whatever that means.

So, does the `Timer.Dispose()` Method release my callback?

Comment: If nobody else references the handler it will eventually be removed by the gc.

Comment: If you dispose `Timer` all handlers which are non static will be cleared out. But just in case I would suggest using `WeakEvent` instead.

Comment: That should never be necessary, expectation is that both the TimerViewModel object and the timer get garbage collected at the same time.  That can be flubbed, we can't see how the TimerViewModel object is referenced, but holding a reference to a disposed object is of course never a wise thing to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the common practice, that the instance that register the handler also unregisters it (I'm pretty sure that Timer doesn't unregister handlers for you in it's dispose method):

```
public void Dispose() {
    m_timer.Elapsed -= timer_Elapsed;
    m_timer.Dispose();
}
```

But in your case where `TimerViewModel` apparently owns the `m_timer` reference, I don't think this is as important since the lifetime of the timer instance will be connected to the lifetime of your `TimerViewModel` instance. If you miss to unregister this handler it won't matter as much because both instances will be garbage collected anyway (together).

The problem arise if the timer-instance was passed in to your viewmodel or is exposed in someway so that it's reference can be held by other objects as well. In that case you can end up with a memory leak when your viewmodel can't be garbage collected because the timer can't be garbage collected because another object has a reference to it etc.

But it's mostly best to be on the sure side and unregister all handlers you also register.

But don't make your viewmodel IDisposable only for this. Just make sure that only the vm-instance can hold the timer-instance-reference and then you can ignore unregistering and disposing the timer altogether. Unless you create alot of these viewmodels and really need to keep the memory footprint low at all times. It will be garbage collected and disposed anyway, when references to the viewmodel is removed. IDisposable is mainly used when you need to be sure that a component cleans up resources straight away when you tell it to, for instance when looping through a set of images and you really need a bitmap to be released before loading another bitmap into memory.